# Javascript design question

Tags: javascript

I am designing a page that has a canvas element which displays 2 images on it.  I can see 3 ways to attach the data to the element.

1)

```
canvas.image1 = new ImageClass(data1);
```

2)

```
canvas.image1 = Image();
global.factory(canvas.image1, data1);
```

3)

```
canvas.image1 = 0;
global.factory(canvas.image1, data1);
```

Are there any other ways?  Which one is better, and why?

Comment: OK, I thought of a new one.  canvas.image1 = global.factory(data1);  Is that better than new?

Comment: canvas.image1 = global.factory(data1);

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of clarity and bug-prevention, I prefer, if possible, to add elements to their parents only when they're fully initialized. So option 1 would seem to be the clearest and option 3 seems like the road to madness.

Of course, a Canvas element has no property image1, so setting it wouldn't do anything.